# Additional validation after button click in Vaadin

Tags: forms, validation, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I need to add an additional validation only when user submits the form.
My form has only 1 textfield with required validation.
When user submits the form I need to check bussiness logic and report the error in the field.

I tried this but the message isn't displayed.

```
submitButton.addClickListener(event -> {
  if (binder.isValid()) {
    if (service.isValid(textField.getValue())) {
      binder.writeBeanIfValid(userIdentity);
      // continue business logic
    }
  }
});
```

I know I could set the value to empty but still not the expected behavior I'm trying to achieve.

[edit]

1. Changing to `addClickListener` as pointed by @Knoobie. Same problem.
2. Got it woking as pointed out by @Tatu in option [2]:

```
submitButton.addClickListener(event -> {
  if (binder.isValid()) {
    var extraValidator = binder.forField(textField).withValidator(businessValidator).bind("field");
    if (binder.validate().getBeanValidationErrors().isEmpty()) {
      binder.writeBeanIfValid(userIdentity);
      // continue business logic
    } else {
      binder.removeBinding(extraValidator);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: What did you try? There is no code that shows any error to the user. Or are you saying that the button listener isn't invoked? That happens because you are not adding a click listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binder by default does not have specific support for this. All validators in the bindings are run. Now this leaves you two options.

1. Add your business logic based validation to Binder using custom validators. And yes, it is perfectly possible to do what ever you want there. Just noting that if you do database queries or something like that in your validator, it will be somewhat slower to execute. Note also that you can have bean level validations add with `binder.withValidator(..)`.
2. Add more bindings to the Binder with new validators in the button click event and call Binder to re-validate programmatically. This will be DIY for two or multistage validation, if you want to separate time consuming business logic based validations and not running them simultaneously with other validators.

Comment: Ty @Tatu.   

[1] As you said the `service.isValid` is a time-consuming task and can't be run with others validations, therefore it's not a option to add it there.   

[2] If I attach a validator after button click, call for a revalidation, if error occur I'd need to retract this validator attached. Is the error message still going to be displayed? I thought we could have a way to additional errors messages outside the scope of binder (or at least use binder to attach these addtional error messages.).

Comment: Option [2] worked.